# idioma, lengua and lenguaje

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

The words *idioma*, *lengua* and *lenguaje* can all be translated as "language".

Are they interchangeable? If not, what are the differences among them? When to use which?

Comment: lengua may also mean tongue

Comment: There seems to be a difference in set phrases. For instance "lenguaje culto" and "lengua culta" are very common but "idioma culta" just isn't used at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting this [Wordreference thread](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=461455&langid=24):

> **Lengua** e **idioma** son prácticamente sinónimos. El problema es que dependiendo del contexto se usa una palabra u otra, pero es una cuestión de uso, no por diferencia de significado.
>
> "**lenguaje**" se utiliza para comunicación en general independiente del idioma. Ej. El lenguaje de los negocios *(...)*, el lenguaje corporal, el lenguaje coloquial, etc.

So *lenguaje* is referring to communication in a broader sense.

You can say "lenguaje no verbal", "lenguaje de los ojos" but not <del>"idioma/lengua no verbal"</del>, <del>"idioma/lengua de los ojos"</del>.

With languages, you can say *idioma español*, *lengua española* and *lenguaje español*.

Answer (score 1):

As you've noticed, they're interchangeable in many contexts.

I observe that Natural Language Processing and [computer language](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenguaje_de_programaci%C3%B3n) are always translated with *lenguaje*. Abstract usages like "body language," "pattern language," and "the language of color" call for *lenguaje*, as does the discussion of languages in general. A slightly antique usage, *habla* is close to *lenguaje* but earthier and less abstract sounding; it is not as common today in this sense as the other three words here discussed.

A specific language, on the other hand, is *lengua* or *idioma*. So far as I can tell from daily use, the principal difference is that one is Greek (*idioma*) and masculine and one is Latin (*lengua*) and feminine and a synonym for the anatomical tongue. That will matter if you ever need to use them in poetry, but in pragmatic speech they're used the same.

They seem close in [Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lengua%2C+idioma&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=10&smoothing=3) when you consider the additional uses of *lengua* for tongue (mostly: delicious beef tongue!). I had the feeling in Mexico that *idioma* was more common, but I trust Google Ngram more than my subjective impression. In any case, the difference in usage is small.

The classic [Sinónimos Castellanos](http://www.archive.org/details/sinnimoscastel00barcuoft) by the great lexicographer Roque Barcia has this to say about *lengua* and *lenguaje*:

> La *lengua* es el órgano con que hablamos: el habla.
>
> El *lenguaje* es la práctica de la lengua: el ejercicio.
>
> Aprendemos la lengua.
>
> Ejercitamos el lenguaje.
>
> Una lengua se fija y se enriquece.
>
> Un lenguaje se corrige y se pule.
>
> Todos los españoles hablan una lengua.
>
> Cada español habla un lenguaje.
>
> La lengua es facultad, disposición, naturaleza.
>
> El lenguaje es estudio, crítica, imitación, hábito, arte.
>
> La lengua nos viene de Dios: es la razón, la mente, el espíritu.
>
> El lenguaje nos viene del mundo: es doctrina y belleza.
>
> Ambas palabras se derivan del latín lingua, voz formada del verbo lingo, que equivale a lamer. De modo que lengua significa literalmente el órgano con que se lame. El considerarla como órgano de lenguaje, como instrumento de razón, como nuncio de nuestra mente, fué un progreso muy posterior a su etimología.

And about habla as opposed to idioma:

> Habla, en lo antiguo fabla, viene de for, fari en latín, phao, phemis en griego, phasko en jónico. Debe notarse quo el for, fari de los latinos significa más bien adivinar, decir sentencias, usar de la palabra en sentido profótico, elevado, por cuya razón este verbo era mucho más noble que dicere y loqui.
>
> La palabra idioma viene inmediatamente del latín idioma, idiomatis, 
>   tomada del griego idioma, voz formada de idios, que significa característico, peculiar, propio. Así fué que la voz idiota, idiotes en griego, no significó primeramente el sentido que hoy tiene, sino que expresaba la idea de una persona que adopta un modo especial de vivir, que se crea un método propio de conducta, extrañándose del trato común de las gentes. Pero como el que vive aislado, según dice nuestro Monlau, suele adquirir pocos conocimientos, idiota pasó á significar rústico, negado, ignorante, hasta llegar á ser término sinónimo de imbécil ó estúpido.
>
> El habla es lenguaje.
>
> El idioma es propiedad.
>
> El habla caracteriza al hombre.
>
> El idioma caracteriza los países.
>
> En una palabra, el habla es un signo de la razón.
>
> El idioma es un signo del habla.

Also see Randolph's abridged extract from the RAE or the original [RAE](http://ww.rae.es).

Answer (score 0):

In Mexican Spanish we use "idioma" if we talk about a foreign languaje for example English, French, etc and "lenguaje" the way we communicate, the way we use the words, wen can have a corporal languaje or another, and lengua we use for example in lengua española, lengua is often used in the grammar books but we do not use it very often.

I hope this helps